# Can I assume input protection diodes in all modern ICs, even when not mentioned in the datasheet?

Tags: protection, input, diode-clamp

I use the [A3906 motor driver](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/brush-dc-motor-drivers/a3906) on a board supplied by 8V. The µC on the board is supplied by 3.3V and is connected to the A3906 via the logic pins. I realised this is a potential pitfall, when supplying the µC only via the programming adapter for programming, debugging and testing, because in that case the motor driver has no supply voltage but is still connected to the logic pins of the µC. I fear this might result in latchup when accidentally powering up one of those pins.

I checked the datasheet of the A3906 for the maximum allowed input current through the protection diodes but could not find a value or any mention of input protection diodes at all.

Can I just assume that all modern ICs have such input protection and just put 10k in series between µC and motor driver to limit the fault current to something like 0.3mA? Or is it likely that some ICs omit this input protection and will be destroyed anway?

Comment: 10k resistors is what I would do.

Comment: Using large resistors near a motor drive seems unwise though have a footprint for *some* series element would be good.  The data sheet specifies the logic voltage limit as an absolute, not relative to the supply voltage.   You might consider motor supply detection and keeping the signals low in its absence with keeper pulldowns.  Simplest might be to power the whole system during programming.

Comment: Look at the absolute maximum voltage ratings on any interface pins.  A rating of less than ort equal 0.6V outside supply rails suggests protection diodes. In this case Vin - abs max is -0.3V - suggesting a negative clamp diode. Vin+Max is 7V abs max with a 9.6V abs max  supply. | Clamp diodes are also mentioned although exactly where and why is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern ICs cannot survive without ESD protection so you can assume that all ICs have this protection.

**However** there are of course exceptions:

- Not all ICs have input protection on all pins, for example a current sense input might be made such that it can sense voltages above or below the supply voltages.
- Not all protections consist of diodes to the supply rails as in the classic ESD protection scheme:

[image]

Source: https://semiengineering.com/how-robust-is-your-esd-protection-are-you-sure/

- Some ICs use ESD protection not like the classic diodes - resistor - diodes like shown above but instead use a "[grounded gate NMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GgNMOS)". Such a device behaves like a fast zener diode. Since this grounded gate NMOS is connected between an input and ground (the ICs substrate) there is no diode to the positive supply rail.
- Some ESD protections rely on **sudden increase in voltage** and these will not clamp / protect against a voltage coming in from an input pin.

So the safest bet would be to **assume that the IC has no protection at all** and that you need to clamp the voltage and limit the current. I would use a series resistor and then some diodes, zeners or TVS so that you can be sure that in input voltage rating of the uC is **never exceeded**.

Also, I would consider it **bad design practice** to rely on the ESD protection of an IC to make the circuit work and/or protect itself. If needed I prefer to have an external circuit to protect against unwanted input voltages and currents as you can never be sure how the ESD protection on a chip will behave. This is especially true if a manufacturer writes the datasheet as if the protection does not exist (no max. input current specified) as then you have **no guarantee** that any current that might flow into an input, is OK.

And remember that for proper input protection you always need to do **two** things:

- limit the voltage (the diodes in the schematic above)
- limit the current (the resistor in the schematic above)

Comment: Do you mean all logic ICs have them or something else but not 'all ICs'? Many don't have these diodes: discrete FET array ICs, for example.

Comment: In normal operation the rated logic input voltage can never be exceeded (because logic voltage is only 3.3V). But for convenience during firmware tests and small series production flashing I would like to connect the programming adapter without using the real power supply. In this case the motor driver has no supply and clamping the logic voltage manually with diodes is not really an option I guess (because I would have to clamp to slightly above 0). But probably you are right, assuming I can input 3.3V to the logic inputs, when I just limit the current is probably foolish and might bite me ;/

Comment: So only safe solution is to always power the complete board, if I really want to make sure that I don't drive the motor driver into latchup.

Comment: @TonyM discrete FET (JFET ?) arrays might fall under the exceptions. It depends on the devices. Even some outputs of some ICs do not have explicit ESD protections, instead they rely on the devices themselves. If a device (like a MOSFET) is large enough, the drain and source can withstand an ESD event.

Comment: *So only safe solution is to always power the complete board* If you can work with that solution then probably that would be the most robust solution.

Comment: The 74LCX series has no input protection to Vcc quite deliberately so they can operate as voltage translators if necessary (in particular 5V to 3.3V).

Comment: Even devices with internal ESD diodes should be protected if there is a likelihood of multiple ESD strikes (as you rightly note) because the typical internal ESD diodes are only rated for a few mA at most.

Comment: @PeterSmith *typical internal ESD diodes are only rated for a few mA at most* Indeed only a few mA **continuous** current (DC) but did you know that during an ESD event, these diodes have to handle up to **a couple of Ampere** for a very short time (up to micro seconds) and **survive that**? The voltage across a diode in such an event can be several volts. That's why a resistor (to limit the current) and a 2nd level diode protection is needed. You can simulate the HBM ESD model in a simulator to see what I mean. ESD is a pain but also interesting at the same time :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have been bitten by ESD on numerous occasions in my younger days (now long past) but it is a great introduction to providing lightning protection - same sort of thing, just rather more extreme :)